# Documentation, Examples, etc of implementing Google's Website Translator

Tags: google-translate

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of Google's Website Translator. Here is a link to the home page for it but short of getting started and a couple of key features, I can't find any actual documentation on it. [Website Translator](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

There's a little bit more information in this post on the Google [Webmaster blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html). Does that help?

Comment: Thank you that did help. For those who stumble across this page, Microsoft's Translator (http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/) has a ton of documentation and lots of options.